# Ionic 3 iOS build and Upload failed due to Razorpay

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3, cordova-plugins, razorpay

I am facing the following issues while uploading the iOS build. The iOS version is 12.3
(Though it was working on 12.1)

[image: upload errors]

Currently, it is showing an error while making the build:

[image: build errors]

Xcode version: 10.2.1 (10E1001)

Here is the plugin list I am using in my app

```
com.razorpay.cordova 0.16.1 "RazorpayCheckout"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.0 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 2.5.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.2.0 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.6.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.12 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Answer (score 0):

Install cordova plugin add com.razorpay.cordova@1.4.5

```
import <Razorpay-swift.h>
```

In project Setting: General> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content> Razorpay.framework to Embed and Signin or Embed without Signing